# How to visualize a sql backup file locally

Tags: sql, mysql

After downloading a backup copy of my databases from phpMyAdmin, how do I open it locally? I know any text editor will do, but I was hoping for it to be organized the way it is in phpMyAdmin.

I tried an app called DbVisualizer, but it just opens one large file with a bunch of code and it looks even messier than a text editor.

Is the only way to set up a localhost? I have incredibly limited knowledge regarding these subjects and just want to be able to review and extract the information from the Wordpress database.

Comment: The best way is maybe to restore it locally on a tool like DBeaver which is free and pretty nice to navigate through the datas and also look at the database schema